# How to Use Go Mod Download with Unreleased Pseudo-Versions

Tags: git, go, go-modules

Since golang 1.13, I've been having this issue where our docker build scripts, which fetch our dependencies using `go mod download`, fail during a git fetch if the given dependency is an unreleased pseudo-version that is on a branch. I'm currently using golang 1.15.

I'm trying to integration test some changes to the referenced go package. I'll call the package `example-go-sdk`. In the git repo for `example-go-sdk`, I've created a branch and pushed some changes. Then in the golang project that uses `example-go-sdk`, I've executed:

```
go get local.url.that.utilizes.goprivate/path/example-go-sdk@824eebca783c68c5ef3cf6db35ad688ad30b58b0
```

where that hash is the hash of the head commit on my branch, which I've double-checked is correct and does have my changes. *The project compiles locally with this just fine.* Even the go mod download works for me.

However, when doing the `go mod download` from a golang:1.15-alpine docker container (after ensuring GOPRIVATE is set correctly), I get this error:

```
go: local.url.that.utilizes.goprivate/path/example-go-sdk@v1.1.2-0.20210329043657-824eebca783c: invalid pseudo-version: git fetch -f origin refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/369a4408a70eeb73ab52db67cb0c1ba8eb165df174d65c9ec995526a9545424b: exit status 128:
    fatal: unresolved deltas left after unpacking
    fatal: unpack-objects failed
```

Is there a way to fix this? Due to some other requirements, I can't merge this branch in `example-go-sdk` to master first before trying to reference it. I've made sure the docker build is using the right version of the referencing project with the updated `go.mod` and `go.sum`, too.

Even though this all works locally for me, a couple other team members also have build issues when referencing the pseudo-version, too, so I'm not sure what the deal is.

Comment: This looks more like a problem with `git` than with Go, but have you tried the current Go release to be sure? Are you certain all commits are pushed correctly? Are you using an old release of git? Verify you can fetch that commit manually using git yourself, since the `go` tool is only calling out to `git`, and `git` is what is failing here.

Comment: Both myself and everyone else is able to fetch that branch and verify that commit hash is the head commit on that branch. This issue has occurred for us in golang 1.13, 1.14, and 1.15 and did not occur until 1.13. I'm not keen on upgrading past that, since we aren't allowed to release with anything else past that quite yet. It seems to me like some kind of caching issue, but not sure. If I tag the commit like v1.2.0-pre and reference it that way, it works.

Answer (score 1):

The `go` command does and will continue to support pseudo-versions for commits for the foreseeable future. This looks like either data corruption within your repo, or a bug in your `git` server and/or client.

Since the failing command is the `git fetch` that attempts to resolve the existing branches and tags in the repo, my guess would be that the issue affects some non-default branch or some existing tag in the repo. That would explain why your pre-release tag workaround works: if the `go` command can find a specific matching tag, then it doesn't need to fall back to fetching “all branches and tags”, and presumably doesn't trigger the underlying `git` issue.

You could perhaps start to narrow it down by trying the failing `git` command in a fresh clone of your repo:

```
git fetch -f origin refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

Note that you can pass the `-x` flag to the `go` command to cause it to (very verbosely!) print all of the `git` commands it executes. That may help you reproduce an exact repository configuration that triggers the underlying bug.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to make this work via pseudo-versions. It seems like since golang 1.13 this functionality of using pseudo-versions instead of semantic versions no longer works unless your module still has a major version of v0. It may or may not be related to the use of GOPRIVATE -- I haven't verified that.

However, a workaround is to use [pre-release versions](https://golang.org/ref/mod#glos-pre-release-version) as described in the official [golang blog](https://blog.golang.org/publishing-go-modules#TOC_3.). Basically adding a new semantic version but appending a string to the end after a dash: `v2.2.2-example.pre.release`

By doing this, `go mod download` was able to find the tag and install the version. Additionally, pre-release tags are not assumed backwards compatible, so users will not automatically get upgraded to that version. They need to explicitly request the pre-release tag.